# Unable to register exisiting K8s cluster to Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am running Rancher 2.6.2 with single-node K8s installation.

I am trying to register an exisitng K8s cluster to rancher but it does not show any thing after I click the button create. It just show:

[image]

I checked all the logs in all rancher pods but they did not show any valuable information.

Please help me with this.

Thank you so much.
Viet

Comment: Have you followed a [rancher's manual on prerequisites and process of joining existung cluster to rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/cluster-provisioning/registered-clusters/)?

Comment: @moonkotte yes, i did as it is the only one document about registering k8s. :(.

Comment: Okay, another option you can do is to check [rancher community - 2.x category forum](https://forums.rancher.com/c/rancher-2x/18) and if there's nothing (I've already spotted a couple of similar questions), you can ask your own one.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I got when I was trying to register k8s cluster via Rancher. I post my solution here to help someone in case:

In my situation, I got limited information like this question for my problem, then.

1. We should check log first:

Go to the k8s cluster node (the one you exec the rancher node register command), `docker ps -a` list all running container; then use `docker logs <container-id>` to check all `*-cattle-*` related container and `etcd`.

Normally, a k8s joined to a rancher will have some necessary containers with status `UP`. For example, if you running a development environment with a 'docker version' rancher, it should be container named `kubelet` and `kube-proxy` etc. more detail can be found at https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/troubleshooting/kubernetes-components/

If none of official troubleshooting can be used to solve your problem, then inspect the docker container with `docker inspect <container-id>`
The rancher agent will run https://github.com/rancher/agent/blob/master/package/run.sh during the initialization. If the container exit unnormally, we should check it's configuration, e.g. compare `CHECKSUM` between your host's CA with rancher's ca. The hosts's ca located at `/etc/kuberneters` the rancher's ca can be reached out via `https://<your rancher domain>/certs`.

Make sure to clean up your previous environment if you are trying to reset a node created by rancher or kubeadm.
e.g. here is what I used to reset the node, check each command before run:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a | grep rancher | awk '{print $1}')
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a | grep k8s | awk '{print $1}')
cd /etc; mv kubernetes kubernetes.rancher.backup
cd ~ ; mv .kube .kube.backup
y | docker volume prune

service docker stop
mount|grep kubelet | awk '{print $3}' | while read mount; do umount $mount; done
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*
rm -rf /var/lib/rancher/*
rm -rf /var/lib/etcd
rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/*
rm -rf /etc/kubernetes
rm -rf /etc/cni
rm -rf /opt/cni
rm -rf /var/lib/cni
rm -rf /var/run/calico
rm -rf /run/secrets/kubernetes.io
test -d /opt/rancher && rm -rf /opt/rancher # For Single Rancher installs
test -d /opt/containerd && rm -rf /opt/containerd
test -d /opt/rke && rm -rf /opt/rke
echo "check docker lib" ;ll /var/lib/docker/
echo "restart dockr"
service docker restart
echo "check docker lib" ;ll /var/lib/docker/
```